# Should we use dependencies in Test while creating framework?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am creating POM framework. My testng.xml runs out of order sometimes. Testng version is 6.11. I researched a lot but did not find any relevant reason. 
Tried many solutions like preserve-order=true that is true by default, clean project and make new testng.xml file. But nothing worked out.

I read setting priority or dependency can be a solution. I am bit confused about using dependencies. Is it good idea to use dependency between @Test methods of different class ? Should test case be dependent on each other? and is it feasible for large projects?

I found mixed readings everywhere , for some it should be dependent while for some test case should be independent.

Please suggest. Thanks !!

Comment: when you use preserve-order="true", did you set the correct value for parallel and thread-count?  if all things correct, try change TestNG version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies were provided by TestNG so that you can express your automation tests the same way in which you would do it manually.

TestNG lets you manage the execution order in two ways.

- Via priorities which are equal to **soft dependencies**. Soft dependencies are basically those sort of dependencies wherein there is an execution order that is required to be maintained but the order is not dependent upon the execution status of the nodes.
- Via dependencies which are equal to **hard dependencies**. Hard dependencies are basically those sort of dependencies wherein there is an execution order that is required to be maintained and the order is dependent upon the execution status of the nodes.

> My testng.xml runs out of order sometimes. Testng version is 6.11. I researched a lot but did not find any relevant reason. Tried many solutions like preserve-order=true that is true by default, clean project and make new testng.xml file. But nothing worked out.

This could perhaps be a bug. So I would strongly urge you to raise an issue on the [TestNG Github issue page](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues) and provide a relevant sample that can be executed to reproduce the problem.

> Is it good idea to use dependency between @Test methods of different class ?

TestNG lets you define dependencies between `@Test` methods that reside within the same test class using `dependsOnMethods`. You can also use `dependsOnGroups` to define dependencies between `@Test` methods that reside within different test classes. There's nothing good or bad about using dependencies. It would eventually boil down to the use case that you are solving. Unit tests are typically expected not to have dependencies but functional tests needn't follow the same rule.

In a nutshell, this is a very generic question for which its hard to provide one answer that will fit the bill. The answers that you will get are all going to be opinionated and based on previous experiences of people.

Comment: Thank you Krishnan for your suggestion !! I get error occasionally, i am trying to back trace or make it reproducible. I will surely raise it in Testng Github issue page.